# Why does ocaml keep miss understanding type?

Tags: ocaml

```
module Value =
struct
  type t = Int of int
end

module M = Map.Make(String)

type expr = 
  | Num of int
  | Add of expr * expr

type t = Value.t M.t (* Value.t is Int of int *)

let rec add_map (st: string list) (e: expr list) (s: t): t =
  match st with
  | [] -> s
  | s1::st -> 
    match e with
    | e1::e -> 
      M.add s1 e1 s; 
      add_map st e s;;
```

In above function, e is list of user defined type expr, and s is user defined map "t = Int M.t" which store int in key of string. Problem is if I compile this, error says that type of e1 is t = t M.t, and I need expr M.t. Clearly e1 is element of expr list, why does ocaml think it is t?? I know M.add need (M.add string expr (map)

Comment: What's the definition of `Value`?

Comment: Value.ml is: type t = Int of int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show the exact error message, but there is a problem with your call to `M.add`: the map `s` has type `Value.t M.t`, but you are giving it a value of type `expr`, not `Value.t`.

Comment: Oh... I see now. Thank you. I was using too many types and I got cunfused. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have a Map type `t` that maps strings to `Value.t` values. But in your `add_map` function, you're adding values of type `expr` to the map.

You need to map values of type `expr` to `Value.t`:

```
let rec expr_to_value_t = function
  | Num n -> Value.Int n
  | Add (e1, e2) ->
    let Value.Int n1 = expr_to_value_t e1 in
    let Value.Int n2 = expr_to_value_t e2 in
    Value.Int (n1 + n2)
```

```
let rec add_map (st: string list) (e: expr list) (s: t): t =
  match st with
  | [] -> s
  | s1::st ->
    match e with
    | e1::e ->
      M.add s1 (expr_to_value_t e1) s;
      add_map st e s
```

However, while this compiles, it does prompt errors about non-exhaustive pattern-matching, and worse, `M.add s1 (expr_to_value_t e1) s` in this context doesn't *do* anything. Maps in OCaml are functional data structures. You don't mutate them, but rather transform them. `M.add` doesn't modify `s`, it just creates a new map with an additional binding.

You can overcome this with relatively few modifications to your function.

```
let rec add_map (st: string list) (e: expr list) (s: t): t =
  match st with
  | [] -> s
  | s1::st ->
    match e with
    | e1::e ->
      let s = M.add s1 (expr_to_value_t e1) s in
      add_map st e s
```

Here I've shadowed the original `s` binding with the new map which is used in the recursive call to `add_map`.  Testing this:

```
# add_map ["hello"; "world"] [Num 23; Num 42] M.empty 
  |> M.bindings;;
- : (string * Value.t) list =
[("hello", Value.Int 23); ("world", Value.Int 42)]
```

This would be a great place to use `List.fold_left2`, assuming both lists are of equal length. Otherwise `Invalid_argument` will be raised.

```
let add_map st e s =
  List.fold_left2 (fun m a b -> M.add a b m) s st e
```

Comment: I though Map.add changes s. Thank you for the information I really needed it